# Destructurar objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy teniendo un dilema al hacer una api con `express` y `mongoose` y es que estoy haciendo destructurando el `req.body` para obtener las variables y luego hago un `if` por cada una para luego asignarlo a otra variable en la cual va a mandar los valores a actualizar:

```js
const createError = require("http-errors");
const { Router } = require("express");
const userRouter = Router();
const User = require("path/to/models/User");

userRouter.put("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { usuario, email, password, role } = req.body;

    let user = {};
    if (usuario) {
      user.usuario = usuario;
    }
    if (email) {
      user.email = email;
    }
    if (password) {
      user.password = password;
    }
    if (role) {
      user.role = role;
    }

    const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, user, {
      new: true,
    });

    if (!result) {
      throw createError.NotFound("Usuario no encontrado");
    }

    res.json(`Usuario ${result.usuario} actualizado`);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

// en el server.js
app.use("users/", userRouter);
```

Mi pregunta es si hay una manera más óptima de hacer esto sin tener que hacer `n * if` por cada parámetro. Sé que ahora parecen pocas pero tengo que hacer lo mismo para otro schema en el que tienen 10 valores.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así.

```
const user={}

const{...campos}=req.body
Object.entries(campos).map(x=>{
if(x[1]){
user[x[0]]=x[1]
}
})
```

Recibes todos los atributos en campos, luego con Object.entries(campos) te devuelve un array para cada clave,valor; luego con map iteras cada array.
En donde el array en cada posición 1 tendrá el valor, si no es nulo se guarda en la variable user.

Comment: de hecho puede ser `user = {...req.body}`

Comment: Si, pero, según menciona, en req.body puede tener valores nulos y según entiendo no quiere que esos valores se guarden innecesariamente en user. @JackNavaRow

Comment: @JackNavaRow serviría en el caso de que quiera mandar todo sin validar valores que no quiera modificar.  Creo que esto me puede servir.

Answer (score -1):

si ya estás usando mongoose puedes dejar que se encargue de todas las validaciones en el modelo, cuales son requeridas o no, te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría el endpoint:

```js
//...
  const {name, email, password, role} = req.body;

  let user = new User({
    name,
    email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10), // Bcrypt hash
    role
  });
//...
```

El modelo:

```js
//...
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "name field is required"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  img: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  state: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  google: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});
//...
```

Como ves puedes especificar si es requerido y colocar algún mensaje adicional, si llega a faltar algún campo requerido entrará en el **catch** y podrás manipular el mensaje de error o usar el que llegue desde el modelo.

Saludos.

Comment: Las validaciones las tengo del lado del schema pero no tiene que ver con eso, sino con que estoy mandando datos que no tienen valor.

Comment: A que te refieres con "datos que no tienen valor"?